# Error installing Mirantis Openstack

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, openstack, proxmox

I am trying to install Mirantis OpenStack on a Linux VM in Proxmox using the provided virtualbox scripts. The problem is I get the error: VT-x is not avalable(VERR_VMX_NO_VMX) when I try to run the launch script.

I have nested virtualization enabled on the server.

I tried with Ubuntu and Linux Mint so far.

I did not change any config.

Any idea why it does that and how to solve the problem?

EDIT:

The server knows VT-d. Does that mean it knows VT-x too or is it 2 separate things?

Answer (score 1):

According to [druss.co](http://druss.co/2015/06/fix-vt-x-is-not-available-verr_vmx_no_vmx-in-virtualbox/), there are approximately three common reasons for this issue:

- VT-x or AMD-V isn't enabled in your BIOS
- Hyper-V virtualization is enabled
- Your CPU doesn’t support VT-x or AMD-V virtualization

---

#### Solution 1: enable VT-x / AMD-V in your BIOS

Restart your computer and enter the BIOS (<kbd>Escape</kbd> / <kbd>F2</kbd> / <kbd>Delete</kbd>, depending on MoB).  Search for your virtualization setting, and set it to enabled.

#### Solution 2: Disable Hyper-V virtualization in Windows

Open a command shell as administrator (run cmd.exe as administrator).  Then execute the following code:

```
dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V
```

Alternatively, you go to the control panel, select `Program section` -> `Turn Windows features on or off`, then disable Hyper-V and reboot.

#### Solution 3: Get a new CPU with VT-X / AMD-V support.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I got virtualization enabled, server runs on proxmox, so no Hyper-V and it totally supports virtualization :D Thanks for the possible solutions tho.

Comment: @BoantaIonut, hmm, sorry.